# Call helper method within Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following AJAX call:

```
   $.ajaxSetup({
      csrfSafeMethod: function(method) {
        // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
        return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
      },

      beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
          if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
              xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
          }
      }
    });
```

I am getting:

```
csrfSafeMethod is not defined
```

Why is `csrfSafeMethod` not visible from inside `beforeSend`?

How can I fix this?

Comment: Just so you know, (at least) GET requests **DO** need CSRF protection

Answer (score 3):

Can't you just define a regular function like so:

```
function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}

$.ajaxSetup({
  beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
      if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
          xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
      }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Why? Because your method is attached to an object which you don't reference in `beforeSend`. You can basically imagine it like this:

```
$.ajaxSetup = function(options) {
  var beforeSend = options.beforeSend;
  // do stuff...
  var xhr = getXHR();
  var settings = getSettings();
  beforeSend(xhr, settings);
};

$.ajaxSetup({
  csrfSafeMethod: function() { ... },
  beforeSend: function() {
    // `this` is the same as if I called this function in the global scope
    // It has no reference to the `options` object
  }
});
```

The actual code in the source code looks like this:

```
// Allow custom headers/mimetypes and early abort
if ( s.beforeSend &&
    ( s.beforeSend.call( callbackContext, jqXHR, s ) === false || completed ) ) {

    // Abort if not done already and return
    return jqXHR.abort();
}
```

Where `s` is some jQuery object, not in any available scope.

As for how to fix this, you need to declare your function elsewhere or assign your options to a referencable object.

```
var options = {
  csrfSafeMethod: function(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
  },

  beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
      if (!options.csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
          xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
      }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `this.csrfSafeMethod` instead of `csrfSafeMethod`

Comment: That won't work. `beforeSend` (or any methods inside of `ajaxSetup`) are not called with the context set to the "options".